# Adding a filter to a MDX query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I'm new to SSAS and need help with what would be equivalent to a where clause in SQL and I'm sure an easy answer for a MDX regular.

I have this pulling values for a multiple select parameter list in report builder but I need to filter out the contracts based on what project the user is currently viewing.  Here is the query that is pulling all the values correctly.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [dimContracts].[ContractName].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [dimContracts].[Contract Name].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue]} ON COLUMNS, 
    [dimContracts].[Contract Name].Children ON ROWS 
FROM [cubeProjectEntities]
```

I need to add what would be equivalant to:

```
WHERE dimContracts.[Project Id] = 1
```

I've added which produces the correct filtered set but from here I don't know how to use the report parameter to get it to work.  Every time I test it just gives and empty dataset.  I have the parameter just printing on the page so I know that it is set correctly.

```
WHERE [dimContracts].[Project Id].[1]
```

This does not work:

```
WHERE [dimContracts].[Project Id].[@ProjectId]
```

And then in Report builder I will pass a parameter to the query to replace the 1 for @projectId.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [dimContracts].[ContractName].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [dimContracts].[Contract Name].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue]} ON COLUMNS, 
    [dimContracts].[Contract Name].Children ON ROWS 
FROM [cubeProjectEntities]
Where (STRTOMEMBER(@projectid))
```

In MDX, the where clause is a slicer. [Here's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216779%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) a good article about the differences between SQL and MDX. 
Here's a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paul_van_der_eerden/archive/2009/03/17/parameterizing-an-mdx-query-with-a-report-parameter-value.aspx) about using SSRS parameters with MDX queries. You'll actually want to pass the entire member name to the query rather than just the value (ex: `[DimContracts].[Project ID].[1]`)

Comment: Yeah I saw that article before but didn't see any help with this particular problem. That really helped me get over that hurdle.  Thanks again